# How to push value into a vector within a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have the struct below

How can i push into a vector within that struct?

```
struct DNA
{
    vector <string>header;
    string DNAstrand;
    double gc;
    int valid;
};
struct World
{
    //  int     numCountries;
    DNA dnas[MAX_DNA_SIZE];
} myWorld;
```

I wish to push a string lets say the string variable is `line` into the vector called header in my dna struct.

How would i go about doing so?
I know that if i wish to add an element into the DNAstand i would just use `myWorld.dnas[counter].DNAstrand = line` But how does this work when i have a vector in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works the same way as with a regular vector. Let's say you have:

```
vector<string> a;
```

Then you would do:

```
a.push_back(line);
```

In your case, it's the same, just the vector's name is `myWorld.dnas[counter].header`, so you would do:

```
myWorld.dnas[counter].header.push_back(line);
```